# how get all value in pathname with url after first slash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

resive pathname

```
pathname: "/kids/dlya-malyshey/platya-i-yubki"
```

using substr I will remove the first slash

```
location.pathname.substr(1,);
```

then i get

```
kids/dlya-malyshey/platya-i-yubki
```

and now the question is how can I take all the values ​​after the first slash? what would i get

```
dlya-malyshey/platya-i-yubki ???
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? You seem to already know that there are methods to manipulate strings.

Comment: get the lenght and the first instance of `/` - then slice via substr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been on correct track. Just split your string by '/' sign and then take all except first.

```js
const pathname = "/kids/dlya-malyshey/platya-i-yubki"
const pathnameParts = pathname.split("/").filter(Boolean);
console.log(pathnameParts);
const expectedResults = pathnameParts.slice(1).join("/")
console.log(expectedResults)
```